# Does dyeing your clothes/cape have any effect in Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

Does dyeing your clothes/cape have any effect in Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood, or is it purely cosmetic?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's purely cosmetic.

Comment: Wow - I'm curious about who is getting the first dye-tag-badge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. It's purely cosmetic and doesn't have any effect in the gameplay or character's 'stats'.