# Does dyeing your clothes in Assassin's Creed 2 have any effect on your character?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

Just wondering whether the different coloured dyes have any effect on the way people interact with your character in Assassin's Creed 2?

Comment: if it is similiar to other games in the series. no, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14587/does-dyeing-your-clothes-cape-have-any-effect-in-assassins-creed-brotherhood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the dyes affect anything other than achievements. The capes, however, change how your notoriety works - either causing you to be unable to become notorious, or automatically becoming notorious, depending on the cape.